# How to show url in android facebook share

Tags: android, image, facebook-graph-api, url

I need to share an image,text and url to facebook. I used the below code to share image and text and its work fine. How can i pass url? I tried with `param.putString("link", mylink);` but it is not working.

```
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    final Uri uri = (Uri) mExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    final String extraText = mPostTextView.getText().toString();
    if (session.isPermissionGranted("publish_actions"))
    {
        Bundle param = new Bundle();


        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArrayData = stream.toByteArray();
            param.putByteArray("picture", byteArrayData);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }


        param.putString("message", extraText);
        Request request = new Request(session,"me/photos", param, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {


            }
        }, null);
        RequestAsyncTask asyncTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        asyncTask.execute();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: you should use `FacebookDialog` for that. It's better.

Comment: I need to pass image from sdcard

Comment: nothing happens. Only text and image is going

Comment: can we put local images in feed

Comment: `postParams.putString("picture",picture);` In this, you can try putting Base64 of your image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71060/discussion-between-divya-and-tushar).

Comment: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: com.facebook.FacebookException: could not construct request body}, isFromCache:false} am getting this error

Comment: I have posted the possible solution [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71060/discussion-between-divya-and-tushar).